# the expresion contain multiple column (and) in True/false expression?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I create new measure as below

```
CountAllVehicleLateEmtracWork =
VAR t =
    SUMMARIZE (
        'tm-all-late-flag',
        'tm-all-late-flag'[Date],
        "tripDistinct", CALCULATE (
            DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'tm-all-late-flag'[tm-all-late-flag-1.emtrac.index] ),
            AND (
                'tm-all-late-flag'[tm-all-late-flag-1.emtrac.index] <> BLANK (),
                'tm-all-late-flag'[Vehicle-work] <> BLANK ()
            )
        )
    )
RETURN
    SUMX ( t, [tripDistinct] )
```

The I got the error The expression contains multiple columns, but only a  single column can be used in a True/false expression that is used as a table filter expression.

Answer (score 0):

Your `CALCULATE` expression references multiple columns in a simple predicate expression. Specifically this portion is not valid in DAX:

```
            AND (
                'tm-all-late-flag'[tm-all-late-flag-1.emtrac.index] <> BLANK (),
                'tm-all-late-flag'[Vehicle-work] <> BLANK ()
            )
```

This is referencing two columns.

You can easily refactor to using two simple predicates in your `CALCULATE`, as all filter args are logically ANDed together:

```
CountAllVehicleLateEmtracWork =
VAR t =
    SUMMARIZE (
        'tm-all-late-flag',
        'tm-all-late-flag'[Date],
        "tripDistinct", CALCULATE (
            DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'tm-all-late-flag'[tm-all-late-flag-1.emtrac.index] ),
            'tm-all-late-flag'[tm-all-late-flag-1.emtrac.index] <> BLANK (),
            'tm-all-late-flag'[Vehicle-work] <> BLANK ()
        )
    )
RETURN
    SUMX ( t, [tripDistinct] )
```

Additionally, you can simplify and improve performance with the refactor as below. Your `VAR t` is materializing an intermediate table in memory and then iterating that table. We can avoid that intermediate allocation as follows:

```
CountAllVehicleLateEmtracWork =
SUMX (
    VALUES ( 'tm-all-late-flag'[Date] ), // VALUES returns the unique values in a column
    // Rather than materializing a new column, we can just return the count inline in
    // the SUMX.
    CALCULATE (
        DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'tm-all-late-flag'[tm-all-late-flag-1.emtrac.index] ),
        'tm-all-late-flag'[tm-all-late-flag-1.emtrac.index] <> BLANK (),
        'tm-all-late-flag'[Vehicle-work] <> BLANK ()
    )
)
```

Additionally, you may want to consider replacing `'Table'[Field] <> BLANK ()` with `NOT ( ISBLANK ( 'Table'[Field] ) )`. In DAX, `0 = BLANK ()` evaluates to TRUE. You are excluding both blanks and zeroes.